# Is this type of report possible?

Tags: custom-report-type

My scenario is that I would like to use ObjectA, ObjectB, and ObjectC in the same report.

ObjectA has a single lookup field which points to ObjectB. 
ObjectC is a child object to ObjectB.

I don't think it's possible without to produce a proper Report/Report Type which could produce that without building a junction object, is it ?

Comment: You would have to create a custom report type

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do that. But I can't figure out a way to make a configuration which would be : ObjectA -> ObjectB -> ObjectC since ObjectB is only referred to in a lookup field in ObjectA.

Comment: It's only possible when you have a lookup field to ObjectA on ObjectB :(

Comment: Yha, that's what I figured. What's weird is that I see a Report Type already made in the system which refers to an object named the same as the lookup field in ObjectA (We'll call the field Title__c)...but there is no object with that same name ! Since it's a Report Type which is part of a Managed Package I can't get into it to see how it's made. My guess is that the object which is also named Title__c is a hidden junction object,part of the Managed Package. Is it possible to completely hide an object which is part of a Managed Package from being seen even by admins/developers with all rights?

Comment: Some report types are created by the system automatically, and have only one level   relationship: Object1 -> Object2 (referenced by a lookup), and these are not customizable. You can hide some report types, and Object access if they are using not standard SysAdmin profile

Comment: Thank you Oleksiy. It must be system created Report Type. Do you know if it is possible to somehow create a hack by copying that Report Type in Eclipse and customizing it further ? I'm going to assume it isn't, but it seems like a cool thing to do.

Comment: You can create the same custom report type with no problem (for you case  select ObjectB as primary, and ObjectA), but it won't allow you to also add ObjectC

Comment: I ended up just creating a joined report. That did the trick. Thanks again.